# 'string' does not contain a definition for/ Error in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a query string in C#. I have found this code in StackOverflow and I really liked it and want to use in my project. However I get an error and I'm stuck with it. Here is the code

```
public static string AddQueryParam(this string source, string key, string value)
{
    string delim;
    if ((source == null) || !source.Contains("?"))
    {
        delim = "?";
    }
    else if (source.EndsWith("?") || source.EndsWith("&"))
    {
        delim = string.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        delim = "&";
    }

    return source + delim + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key)
        + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value);
}

private string QueryStringCreator()
{
    string queryString = "http://www.something.com/something.html"
    .AddQueryParam("name", "jason")//I get the error here
        .AddQueryParam("age","26");

    return queryString;
}
```

And the error is :

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'AddQueryParam' and no
>   extension method 'AddQueryParam' accepting a first argument of type
>   'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Are you `using` the namespace that the extension method's class is in?  Do you get any other compiler errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make extension method `AddQueryParam`, put it to a separate static class.

```
static class StringExtension
{
    public static string AddQueryParam(this string source, string key, string value)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

BTW, I expect that the posted code should give another error:

> Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Answer (score 2):

The `AddQueryParam` is an *extension* method. So you should place it inside a `static` class.

```
static public class Extensions
{
    public static string AddQueryParam(this string source, string key, string value)
    {
        string delim;
        if ((source == null) || !source.Contains("?"))
        {
            delim = "?";
        }
        else if (source.EndsWith("?") || source.EndsWith("&"))
        {
            delim = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            delim = "&";
        }
    } 
    return source + delim + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key)
    + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value);
}
```

For more information about extension methods, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

An `Extension Method` needs to be declared inside a non generic, static class.

From the [C# Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx#csharp3.0overview_topic4):

> **26.2.1 Declaring Extension Methods**
>
> Extension methods are declared by specifying the keyword this as a modifier on the first parameter of
>   the methods. Extension methods can only be declared in non-generic,
>   non-nested static classes. The following is an example of a static
>   class that declares two extension methods.

Declare it like this:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
   public static string AddQueryParam(this string source, string key, string value)
   {
      string delim;
      if ((source == null) || !source.Contains("?"))
      {
          delim = "?";
      }
      else if (source.EndsWith("?") || source.EndsWith("&"))
      {
          delim = string.Empty;
      }
      else
      {
         delim = "&";
      }

      return source + delim + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key)
        + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value);
   }
}
```