# manipulate instance by name in singleton c# winforms

Tags: c#, string, winforms, user-controls, converters

**string Go_Page  .... string variable contains name of instance userControl.
I am trying to manipulate instance userControl by name (string Go_Page  ) .  help pls**

```
            string Go_Page;


            if (!FrmMain.panelMain.Controls.Contains(Go_Page.Instance))
            {
                FrmMain.panelMain.Controls.Clear();
                FrmMain.panelMain.Controls.Add(Go_Page.Instance);
                Go_Page.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                Go_Page.Instance.BringToFront();
            }
            else
            { Go_Page.Instance.BringToFront(); }
```

i get this Error :

***Error CS1061 'string' does not contain definition for 'Instance'***

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865628/string-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-error-in-c-sharp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['string' does not contain a definition for/ Error in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865628/string-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-error-in-c-sharp)

Comment: `panelMain` looks to be some sort of GUI control.  What framework are you using?  [tag:winforms]?  [tag:wpf]?  [tag:xamarin.forms]?  Something else?  Also, your code doesn't seem like it would compile.  Should the code starting with `if (UC_Vars_PROTECT == "PS")` be outside the `switch` statement?  Can you please [edit] your question to clarify?

Comment: i'm using winforms framework, and yes if statement should be outside the switch statement. But I'm still confused how should I make it work. I have to check if the instance inside panelMain , if not panelMain.Controls.Add(instance)

Comment: Well in that case see [Get control by name, including children](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8737091) or [Find control by name from Windows Forms controls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3898588/3744182).  You would use those answers to find a child control of `panelMain` with the specified name, then if not present add it.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Also, is `UC_Vars_PSNP` the name of the control, or the name of the **c# type** of the control?  Your question text says the latter but the title says the former.

Comment: it's custom user_control  . like a frame . UC_Vars_PSNP the name of the control

Comment: OK then what happened when you tried the solutions from [Get control by name, including children](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8737091) and/or [Find control by name from Windows Forms controls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3898588/3744182)?  Did those work?  If not, can you share a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

Try  this method to convert string to class instance:

If user control class in current assembly,use:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
```

else:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("AssemblyPath");
```

Class Instance:

```
object obj = assembly.CreateInstance("ClassFullName"); //contains namespace
```

Or Try:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("ClassFullName"); //contains namespace
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: Good answer, but you need a public default constructor to use this `Activator.CreateInstance` overload. There is also an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Object___) which accept constructor parameters.

Comment: Yes,```assembly.CreateInstance``` also can accept  constructor parameters by args ```CreateInstance(string typeName, bool ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, object[] args, CultureInfo culture, object[] activationAttributes)```

Comment: The bigger problem with this answer is that it's entirely possible that the OP is trying to manipulate an _existing_ instance, e.g. a singleton implementation, of the `UserControl` in question. Creating a _new_ instance is useless in that scenario.

Comment: yes its a singleton so I'm trying to manipulate an existing instance by name   witch is this `string UC_Vars_PSNP`.

Comment: If  set  control's fixed name,you can try ```panelMain.Controls.ContainsKey("control's name")```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!panel.Controls.Contains(UCMangerReport.Instance))
            {
                panel.Controls.Add(UCMangerReport.Instance);
                UCMangerReport.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                UCMangerReport.Instance.BringToFront();
            }
            else
            {
                UCMangerReport.Instance.BringToFront();
            }

Error=>Error3'appReport.UCMangerReport' does not contain a definition for 'Instance'
```

Comment: You should generally accompany your answer with an explanation of what you fixed/changed so that it is clear for readers